# Multiple charts in SAP Business Objects Webi?

Tags: business-objects, webi

Has anyone tried dynamic charts (multiple charts based on data available)  in SAP Business Objects WebI?

I did try the sections which is available in WebI, however I need to place charts side-by-side while sections show charts one below other.

Comment: Your assessment about sections is correct. Why can't you place one chart next to another?

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly place charts side-by-side. I created a report based on the eFashion universe returning Year, Quantity sold, and Sales revenue. I have one table displaying the raw data and three side-by-side charts.

[image]

Comment: Hi Isaac, Thanks for your reply. Are these 3 different charts or one chart which dynamically got divided in 3 based on data?
Our requirement is that there will be single chart specification (Ex. Sales Revenue by country) and based on each country received from data (Ex. Australia, India, US, UK) , there should be 4 charts placed side by side.

Comment: These are 3 charts based on the data from the same query. I don't think you can dynamically divide data into separate charts. Do you have a set number of countries? If so, you could create one chart and filter on your first country. Then copy it and paste it to the right for as many countries as you have each time changing the filter to the next country. You could also check the "Hide when empty" checkbox so if there is no data for a given country the chart will disappear. You would also want to make the charts position relative to each other so there aren't blanks if a chart is hidden.